# Flutter _Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>' is not a subtype of type 'Filters' in type cast

Tags: flutter

Cant get this simple model to work. Any ideas?

```
      final extractedData = {
        "regions": [
          {"id": 1, "region": "Ljubljana", "image": "ljubljana.jpg"}
        ]
      } as Filters;
```

and the model:

```
class Filters with ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Regions> regions;

  Filters({required this.regions});
}

class Regions with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String region;
  final String image;

  Regions({required this.id, required this.region, required this.image});
}
```

I tried multiple definitions but with no success. I'm new at flutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this ?

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class RegionsRepository extends ChangeNotifier {
  Filters? _items;

  Filters? get filters => _items;

  Future<void> loadJsonData(Map<String, dynamic>? params) async {
    final url = Uri.https('nepremicnine.in', '/api/filters', params);
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final result = json.decode(response.body);
        final regions = result['regions'];
        _items = Filters(
          regions:
              regions.map<Regions>((json) => Regions.fromJson(json)).toList(),
        );
        notifyListeners();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw Exception(error);
    }
  }
}

class Filters with ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Regions> regions;

  Filters({required this.regions});
}

class Regions with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String region;
  final String image;

  Regions({required this.id, required this.region, required this.image});

  //Youcan name it to fromMap too or anything you want
  factory Regions.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Regions(
      id: json['id'],
      region: json['region'],
      image: json['image'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I used json.decode because I'm getting the data from the server. The problem is I guess how model if defined, because if specify it as Map<String, dynamic> the problem goes away. It just wont specify as Filters. Any ideas?

Comment: because the response from the server cannot directly use the "as" model, unless you parse the response first, for example, if you have a variable worth "1" we cannot define it using as int. btw can i see your real code to help with what you want?

Comment: Future<void> loadJsonData(Map<String, dynamic>? params) async {
    final url = Uri.https('nepremicnine.in', '/api/filters', params);
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Filters;

      _items = extractedData;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

I use json.decode from the server.

Comment: check my new answer, maybe like that?